# Error while installing libav on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, libav

I am getting this error while installing libav on ubuntu 14.04

(Reading database ... 357718 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libvpx/x264_0-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking x264 (0-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /home/prashant/libvpx/x264_0-1_amd64.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/local/bin/vpxdec', which is also in package libvpx 1:201605142355-git-1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /home/prashant/libvpx/x264_0-1_amd64.deb

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /home/prashant/libvpx/x264_0-1_amd64.deb

If "--force-overwrite" doesn't work, try "--force-all"